# python django-import-export import model data even if there are not data

Tags: python, django, csv, django-import-export

I'm using `django-import-export` package to import data from a csv file, basically following the getting started tutorial in [readthedocs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

I'm confused with a behavior of the package in a simple configuration.

My model is like:

```
class Experiment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    research_project = models.ForeignKey(
       ResearchProject, null=False, blank=False
    )
```

I created a csv file to test import. The file `/tmp/experiment.csv` is simple:

```
h1,h1,research_project
v1,v2,66
```

(Note that the first two columns of csv have headers that not correspond to any of the fields models)

Then, I created a Resource:

```
class ExperimentResource(resources.ModelResource):

class Meta:
    model = Experiment
    exclude = ('id', )

def export(self, queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Experiment.objects.filter(id=kwargs['id'])
    return super(ExperimentResource, self).export(queryset, *args, **kwargs)

def get_instance(self, instance_loader, row):
    return False
```

Now, I can try to import `/tmp/experiment.csv` data, by calling:

```
dataset = Dataset().load(open('/tmp/experiment.csv').read())
result = ExperimentResource().import_data(dataset)
print(result.has_errors())  # for debug
```

Last line prints `False`, as data has effectively imported and a line has added to the database. But `title` and `description` was filled with an empty string, even if in `Experiment` model this two attributes have `blank=False`.

My questions are: why `django-import-export` allows saving empty strings for models that have fields with `blank=False` parameters? And why the package do not check for the headers of the dataset for corresponding fields model?

How to make `django-import-export` to check for headers and empty strings in fields that have `blank=False`?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>That's because `blank=False` is only relate to forms, as it is described in docs [`blank`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#blank):</strike>

> If `True`, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is False.
>
> Note that this is different than `null`. `null` is purely
>   database-related, whereas `blank` is validation-related. If a field has
>   `blank=True`, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a
>   field has `blank=False`, the field will be required.

If you wan't to forbid to save empty values, set `null=False`, but [be aware of `null` for `CharField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#null)

UPDATE: since solution above did not help, another possible solution would be provide validators on `CharField` fields. The [MinLengthValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/#minlengthvalidator) can help you validate your non-empty-required fields.

Apply it as follows:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, validators=[MinLengthValidator(1)])
description = models.TextField(blank=False, validators=[MinLengthValidator(1)])
```

Comment: Thanks @vishes_shell, but with `null=False` same problem happens. Fact is `django-import-export` looks like skip the own model validation.

Comment: @Caco have you applied migrations related to change of `null=True`?

Comment: You can consider as yes @vishes_shell.

Comment: @Caco can you try another solution that i've provided?

Comment: I think can be solve in the updated answer. Thanks again @vishes_shell. By now I prefer to keep models without changes. I don't want to change models because of the package. Maybe that's another way to set up `django-import-export` `Resources`.

Answer (score 0):

"why django-import-export allows saving empty strings for models that have fields with blank=False parameters" =>

seems that django-import-export ignore blank parametr, but you can add null=False it will add constrains also on DB level) and woldn't allow django-import-export to write blunk lines, i assume? that you will get Error on procass